# Wordpress filter that hook after each action/filter hook

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions, security, virus

In my wordpress site virus script added in footer on wp_footer action.

I try many techniques, but i cant find virus hook location.

Is there any wp action/filter, that hook after each action /filter hooked including hooked output data?

I mean, if some one hook

```
add_action("wp_footer","abc");
function abc(){
  echo "inside content";
}
```

I want this.

```
output: inside content
function ABC, file : foo.php
```

I am using this code, that only return list of hooks.

```
add_action('wp', function(){ 
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($GLOBALS['wp_filter']); 
      echo '</pre>';
      exit; 
});
```

Comment: The plugin [Debug Objects](https://github.com/bueltge/debug-objects) list you all functions, that are fired on a hook. Maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Check also if it was added by JavaScript. To list all the functions hooked wp_footer, this might help:

```
global $wp_filter;
var_dump( $wp_filter['wp_footer'] );
```